# PHP redirect page after files are uploaded

Tags: php, redirect, upload

Im looking to redirect back to my home page once files have been uploaded, I currently have an echo statement indicating that a file has been uploaded (when done so). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
  $tags[]= $_POST['Sport'];
  $tags[]= $_POST['bcTags1'];
  $tags[]= $_POST['bcTags2'];
  $tags[]= $_POST['bcTags3'];
  $tags[]= $_POST['hiddenTag'];
  $metaData = array(
    'name' => $_POST['bcVideoName'],
    'shortDescription' => $_POST['bcShortDescription'],
    'tags' => $tags
  );
# Rename the video file     
       $file = $_FILES['theVideoFile'];     
       rename($file['tmp_name'], '/tmp/' . $file['name']);     
       $file_location = '/tmp/' . $file['name'];      
       # Send video to Brightcove     
       $id = $bc->createMedia('video', $file_location, $metaData);

echo $id.'Uploaded Successfully!';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) normally:

```
  //echo $id.'Uploaded Successfully!'; <--- output breaks header()
  header('Location: /yourpage.php');
  exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: yourscript.php");
die();
```

This will redirect, but it has to be used before ANYTHING has been echoed.

Comment: Better adding the `die()`.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that you cannot modify the headers after output has been written (like `echo 'uploaded';`).  Also, you may not always redirect (depending on what is in your script) unless you end the script right after modifying the header with `exit;`.

`header('Location: http://example.com'); exit;`

Answer (score 1):

Provided that nothing has been outputted yet, you could do in place of the echo statement:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could set a variable (example: $success) to true if the upload is OK and then add the following further down the page;

```
<?php

if($success == true){
  echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
  echo "alert('Upload successful!'); window.location.href='http://splash21.com';";
  echo "</script>\n";
}

?>
```

This will allow you to tackle both successful and failed uploads

Comment: Great help thanks! any idea on how I could add a pop up notification if the upload didn't complete? (maybe use an else statement?)